# Select custom type and regular type in one query using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm wondered if there any way to select custom type and regular type in one query using Hibernate.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
Query query = db.createQuery("select e.id, new com.util.data.MyCustomOBJECT(e.firstName,e.lastName, e.description) from elements e");
```

but get error:
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 14 [select...

any Idea?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using? Pretty sure that Hibernate 6+ supports this properly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure older versions going back to H2 supported it too. (It's even required by the JPA 1 spec.)

Comment: I'm using hibernate 5+